# angular template with ng-class

Tags: angularjs

i would like to use a template in my directive that uses ng-class

my old way, just with class and

```
template: '<div class="testclass-{{data.attr}}"></div>'
```

works but is clumpy, whenever i try to add ng-class i get errors, how exactly do i have to escape all the "´s and '´s im using there?

```
ng-class="{
'is-checked-icon-bg-0': (entry.prokraIndex== '0' && entry.stateOfEntry=='checked')}"
```

would be an example that works if i add it in html itself

btw does it matter if i use " or ' ? the syntax above was somewhere in an example

```
template: '<div ng-class="{'is-checked-icon-bg-0': (entry.prokraIndex== '0' && entry.stateOfEntry=='checked')}"></div>'
```

gives me an error when used in the directive template or if i substitute all 's with "s it works but the style is not applied, does it even work with ng class?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `'` inside a string enclosed in `'`, so you need to escape them:

```
template: '<div ng-class="{\'is-checked-icon-bg-0\': (entry.prokraIndex== \'0\' && entry.stateOfEntry==\'checked\')}"></div>'
```